# How can I convert a .MXF video file to .MKV with Ubuntu?

Tags: video, media, convert, mkv

I have some videos recorded on a Sony PXW-X70 camera that I wish to convert to something else, possibly an .mkv file. What program or command line utility can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like mxf containers *usually* hold mpeg2video which FFmpeg easily converts, although there are some variations on this codec theme. I illustrate one conversion method with a publicly available sample file:

First download this sample file:

```
wget http://www.freemxf.org/samples/freeMXF-mxf1.mxf
```

This converts easily enough with *the latest* FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i freeMXF-mxf1.mxf -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 output.mkv
```

And then all should be well :)

**A few extra points:**

- If you are troubled by FFmpeg errors with the Repository FFmpeg get the latest version here:

  Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu, Debian, or Mint 
  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu
- If you prefer a different container another good choice would be mp4:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i freeMXF-mxf1.mxf -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 output.mp4
  ```
- And if you want to use the aged avi container something like the following should do the trick:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i freeMXF-mxf1.mxf \
         -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 2 -vtag XVID -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 \
         -mbd rd -flags +mv4+aic -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 \
         output.avi
  ```

**References:**

- [Material Exchange Format (MXF) Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Exchange_Format)

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing this with my video, but I got these two errors while the program converted: `[h264 @ 0x2addce0] PPS changed between slices`, `[h264 @ 0x2addce0] decode_slice_header error`. The resulting .mkv file did not have sound, and the lower half of the video was covered with a sort of green band.

Comment: @L42 Can you upload one of your sample mxf files for me to examine?

Comment: The ones I have right now are all >13gb of size. But I will record a short video in a couple of days and upload that so you can look at it :)

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of response. I actually haven't been to the office where we have the camera since my last post. I will try to go there before christmas :)

Comment: If I wanted to get another output file format would it be as simple as changing the extension in the output? e.g. `output.avi` instead

Comment: @TokeFaurby I have added some details regarding this to my answer, avi is not such a good choice...

Comment: Thanks @adnrew.46! But the general principle holds, right? For any supported file type I just use the appropriate extension? I guess my question is whether any of the other flags need to be adjusted.

Comment: @TokeFaurby Yes, exactly. Only issue is that with the command line I have suggested: H.264 sits uneasily in avi container, you would have to modify the command line a little...

Comment: @TokeFaurby I have added an avi example :)

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you can do it with ffmpeg
**sudo apt-get install ffmpeg**

https://superuser.com/questions/559820/converting-from-mxf-to-mpeg-format-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but just got a lot of these errors: `[mpeg @ 0x1e0c7a0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=397420 size=400525` `[mpeg @ 0x1e0c7a0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=399461 size=400525`. Do you know what I can do to make it work?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I did not even know that format existed until I read your question